# Shortcode meant to output custom taxonomy instead outputting the word 'array'

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

Attempting to output a custom post type taxonomy (property_type) as a shortcode. At the moment where it should output the taxonomy it simply outputs the word Array. Quite new to php, so possibly something simple I'm missing, or completely barking up the wrong tree.

Code is:

```
function prop_type_shortcode() { 

 $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'property_type');
    if ($terms) {
        $out = array();
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'property_type') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
        }
        echo join( ', ', $out );
    } 
    
 

return $terms;
} 

add_shortcode('type', 'prop_type_shortcode');
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the array from `wp_get_post_terms()`. Instead you should be returning your processed text.

```
function prop_type_shortcode() {
    global $post;

    $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'property_type');

    if (!$terms) {
        return '';
    }

     $out = array();

     foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $out[] = '<a class="' .$term->slug .'" href="' .get_term_link( $term->slug, 'property_type') .'">' .$term->name .'</a>';
     }

    return join( ', ', $out );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I tried it and am now getting no output at all. Went through it to see if I could figure out why but got stuck.

Comment: Forgot to declare global `$post` object.